# Extract internal contours (HOLES) OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, imagemagick, computer-vision, contour

Isn't there a way to extract or display holes, while discarding exterior contours?

I can display exterior contours only, by using **CV_RETR_EXTERNAL** but there seems to be no way for displaying interior contours (holes) only.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this with the C interface:

```
cvFindContours(tmp, storage, &srcSeq, sizeof(CvContour), 
                       CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        while (srcSeq)
        {
            if (CV_IS_SEQ_HOLE(srcSeq))
            {
                // do something with the hole
            }
            srcSeq = srcSeq->h_next;
        }
```

If you are using the C++ interface then you will have to use the hierarchy parameter from FindContours() to see if a contour is a hole.

Comment: Nope it didnt work...
what i want is to display contours by using cvDrawContours(src1,c,red,blue,1,0.25,8);
I cant seperate holes from exterior contours... both exterior and interior contours have same flags most of the times 
...only few exterior contours have a different flag...

in short it displays both exterior contours and holes in case of ur code...thanks for the help anyways ;)

Comment: Well to only draw the hole that you have checked in the 'if' you will have to call cvDrawContours with maxLevel parameter = 0. Something like this: cvDrawContours(src1, srcSeq, red, blue, 0, 0.25, 8);